# Creating a json with array inside PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to implement it something like this

```
private static function getData($datas) {

    $days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    $days_aliases = ['SUN', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT'];

    $open_rates = array();

    foreach ($datas as $data) {

        $date = Carbon::parse($data->created_at)->format('l');

        for($i = 0; $i < count($days); $i++) {

            if($date == $days[$i]){

                $open_rates['x'][$i] = $days_aliases[$i];
                $open_rates[$data->name][$i] = (int)$data->open_rate;

            } 

        }

    }

    return $open_rates;

}
```

But the result is like this.

{
"x": {
"0": "SUN",
"1": "MON",
"2": "TUE",
"3": "WED",
"4": "THU",
"5": "FRI",
"6": "SAT"
}
}

How to make an array like this PHP?

```
json: {
    'Day Pass' : [40, 10, 99, 50],
    'Day Pass' : [40, 10, 99, 50],
    'Day Pass' : [40, 10, 99, 50],
    'Day Pass' : [40, 10, 99, 50],
    'Day Pass' : [40, 10, 99, 50]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a numeric-indexed array. Note that you can't have multiple keys with the same name in an array, so you need different names for "Day pass", otherwise you'd be overwriting them:

```
<?php
$json = [
    "json" => [
        "Day pass" => 
            [40, 10, 99, 50],
        "Day pass2" => 
            [40, 10, 99, 50],
        "Day pass3" => 
            [40, 10, 99, 50],
        "Day pass4" => 
            [40, 10, 99, 50],
    ],
];
print_r(json_encode($json));
```

Gives the correct result:

```
{
    "json": {
        "Day pass": [40, 10, 99, 50],
        "Day pass2": [40, 10, 99, 50],
        "Day pass3": [40, 10, 99, 50],
        "Day pass4": [40, 10, 99, 50]
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Q5Di2)

Using the same key instead, gives you one item:

```
<?php
$json = [
    "json" => [
        "Day pass" => 
            [40, 10, 99, 50],
        "Day pass" => 
            [40, 10, 99, 50],
        "Day pass" => 
            [40, 10, 99, 50],
        "Day pass" => 
            [40, 10, 99, 50],
    ],
];
print_r(json_encode($json));
```

Result:

```
{
    "json": {
        "Day pass": [40, 10, 99, 50]
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/c506g)

---

The problem with your specific code is that, in order to have `json_encode()` return a JSON array (instead of an object), the PHP array needs to be a numeric sequential 0-indexed array. What you can do is pass the array through `array_values()` in order to only preserve the values and reset the keys:

```
<?php
$open_rates = [];
$open_rates["x"]["0"] = "Sun";
$open_rates["x"]["2"] = "Mon";
var_dump(json_encode($open_rates)); // JSON object
$open_rates["x"] = array_values($open_rates["x"]);
var_dump(json_encode($open_rates)); // JSON array
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ONWtn)

Comment: How can we do it inside a loop? I tried to implement that. But it returns some array index which I don't want

Comment: Change it to this: `$open_rates['x'] = []; if ($date == $days[$i]) { $open_rates['x'][] = $days_aliases[$i]; /* etc */ }`

Comment: result is like this 
"x": [],
"test4": {
"0": 0,
"1": 100,
"2": 0,
"3": 100,
"4": 133,
"5": 67,
"6": 0
},

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time editing this because I'm on my iPad. You're getting the results because of non sequential keys. `json_encode()` will give you a JSON array only if it's number indexed, sequential and starting at 0 (basically a normal array). Look [here](https://3v4l.org/NE0q4). It'll get you in the right direction using `array_values()`.

Comment: Awesome dude array values is the answer.. Can you edit your answer so that I can check it?

Comment: Great! Sure, just a second.

Answer (score 1):

The json you gave is not a valid `json`, keys shouldn't repeat inside a valid `json`

Assuming you meant:

```
json: {
    'Day Pass 1' : [40, 10, 99, 50],
    'Day Pass 2' : [40, 10, 99, 50],
    'Day Pass 3' : [40, 10, 99, 50],
    'Day Pass 4' : [40, 10, 99, 50],
    'Day Pass 5' : [40, 10, 99, 50]
}
```

It can be written in php as

```
<?php
$json = array(
    "json" => array(
        "Day Pass 1" => array(40, 10, 99, 50),
        "Day Pass 2" => array(40, 10, 99, 50),
        "Day Pass 3" => array(40, 10, 99, 50),
        "Day Pass 4" => array(40, 10, 99, 50),
        "Day Pass 5" => array(40, 10, 99, 50)
    )
)
```

Comment: How can we do it inside a loop? I tried to implement that. But it returns some array index which I don't want

Answer (score 0):

The example that you have written is wrong. Object cannot have same key repeated. So assuming that key is different it should be something like this in PHP:

```
$json = array(‘day pass’ => array(40,10,99,50), ‘day pass2’ => array(20,30,30))
```